# Are there any objective reasons to prefer a prefix over a suffix for an environment-specific login?

Tags: authentication, access-control, naming-convention

When creating environment specific logins (development, qa, staging, production, etc.) I'm faced with the choice of making the denotation a prefix or a suffix to the login name.

#### Examples

```
prod_MyAppLogin
MyAppLogin_prod
```

Is there any reason why I should prefer one strategy over the other?

(Obviously, I should be consistent with whichever choice I make)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd rather have the environment be the suffix assuming I had to pick one convention.  Otherwise, it's too difficult to navigate through lists of login names that all use the same first five characters.

Of course, if given my choice, I would prefer to use neither the prefix nor the suffix.  I'd rather keep the same username in all environments and vary my password and TNS alias to identify which system I'm connecting to.

Comment: I couldn't have said it better. (+1)